# Maximum Recursion Depth? How to prevent?

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to recurse my list.

but even if I have only one task under another task it runs ERROR maximum recursion depth? Why?

task_recurse.html

```
{% if items %}
  <ul>
    {% for task in items %}
      <li>
        {{ task.name }}

        {% with items=task.subtask.all template_name="task_recurse.html" %}  
          {% include template_name %}
        {% endwith %}


      </li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
{% endif %}
```

task.html

```
{% include "task_recurse.html" with items=items %}
```

Task model

```
  class task(models.Model):

  name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

  notes = models.TextField()

  created = models.DateTimeField()

  created_by = models.ForeignKey(User)

  subtask = models.ManyToManyField('self')
```

It gives me a error on the view? Is this the problem?

```
def tasks(request): 

items = task.objects.all() 
return render(request, 'tasks.html', {'items': items})
```

So two questions really:

1) Why does this return maximum recursion depth when I only have two tasks where only one task is a subtask ?

2) How can I prevent infinite recursion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you defined `subtask = models.ManyToManyField('self')` so taskA has taskB subtask and taskB has taskA subtask
You can see it when you comment out include template in task_recurse.html

Output:

```
Task B
   Task A
Task A
   Task B
```

You have created a graph relation instead of tree.
Change you ManyToMany relationship to ForeignKey and you will get desired results:

```
subtask = models.ForeignKey('self',null=True, blank=True)
```

I also included null=True, blank=True as the first element (tree head) has no subtask